# How do I prevent KitKat from showing two alarm icons in the notification bar?

Tags: alarm, google-now, 4.4-kitkat, nexus-5

I have Nexus 5 with KitKat. When I set an alarm with Google Now, I see this:

[image: alarm icons]

Why is there two icons? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the one on the right is the icon that shows you have an alarm on (always shows when you have an alarm). The one on the left is a notification and should disappear if you dismiss the notification.

Comment: Close. The one on the left shows up when the alarm is close to ring apparently. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are ROOTED then use tool called "Xposed Framework"
Install it and download module named "Gravitybox KK"
Install and Reboot.
Finally go to Gravitybox KK>> StatusBar Tweaks >> Clock Settings >> There will be an option called "Hide Alarm icon"  (Check it, Done)
Hope it ll help you.

Answer (score 0):

Under settings for the Alarms uncheck "Show Icon"

https://www.dropbox.com/s/l3xuk7cmipf98da/Screenshot_2013-12-21-08-25-23.png
https://www.dropbox.com/s/4rs4mx2elwi5npk/Screenshot_2013-12-21-08-25-33.png

Comment: This is to enable and disable the icon on the right, not the one on the left.

Comment: Question doesn't specify which icon to remove.

Answer (score 0):

Settings - apps - all, select the clock app and uncheck show notifications